# Java EE 5 dependency injection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5

Since Java EE 5 does not have CDI, how does DI work in here?

Can an EJB be injected with `@EJB` in a class that is a non-EJB? 
Can an `EntityManager` be injected with `@PersistenceContext` in a class that is a non-EJB (container managed not resource local `EntityManager`)? Or the only solution to bring the resources in non-EJB classes is by JNDI lookup?

By non-EJB class I mean a class that is not annotated with `@Stateless`/`@Statefull` or others.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are pre-CDI frameworks you can use in this situation - Guice, PicoContainer, even the dreaded Spring. They don't have an natural ability to inject EJBs or the contextual `EntityManager` into their objects, but it should be fairly simple to build a bridge which would let them do so, although this margin is too small to contain an explanation of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/injection-141192.html

> Keep in mind that a Java EE 5 platform container can handle the
>   injections transparently only when they are used on container-managed
>   components, such as EJB beans, Servlets, and JavaServer Pages (JSP)
>   technology tag handlers.

onjava has an article: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/01/04/dependency-injection-java-ee-5.html

It presents a readable table of which managed-components (per container) that support injection of what type of resources.

Comment: Suppose I have an EJB (POJO annotated with @Stateless) that has some fields that are container-managed components, say an EntityManager annotated with @PersistenceContext and other EJB annotated with @EJB/ If I want to use the functionality of this EJB in a non container managed class I can look it up via JNDI; but will the EntityManager and the other EJB be injected and ready to be used?

Comment: I believe so, you experiencing different behaviour?