# Inject CDI bean into EJB (weblogic 10)

Tags: java, weblogic, cdi, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

I'm getting `NullPointerException` when trying to inject a CDI bean into an EJB.

My ejb is

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "myEjb")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyEjb implements MyEjbLocal, MyEjbRemote {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyEjb .class);

    @Inject
    @Named("myService")
    private MyService myService;

    public MyEjb () {

    }

    public MyEjb (MyService myService) {
        this.myService= myService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        logger.info("Injected myService" + myService+ " into this " + this);
    }
```

And actually `myService` is always null.
Here is how I initialize `myService` by using CDI and a Factory

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceFactory {
    private MyService myService;

    @Inject
    @Named("myDao")
    private MyDao dao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        myService= new MyServiceImpl(dao);
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("myService")
    public MyService myService() {
        return myService;
    }
}
```

And `MyService` is just without annotations

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {


    private final MyDao myDao;

    public MyServiceImpl(MyDao dao) {
        this.myDao = dao;
    }
```

Well, if I invoke the EJB then `myService` is always `null`....what I'm missing? (`bean.xml` is there)

Am I missing something around the interaction ejb/cdi?

Comment: Are you sure weblogic 10 supports java ee 6?

Comment: Wrong tag, it's jee 5 you're right

Comment: My point being `@Inject` was introduced with java ee 6.

Comment: Well my fault, I thought it was already there in jee 5....

Comment: Well, now my question is more...how can I do the same kind of injection in jee 5?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530409/java-ee-5-dependency-injection) helps.